# How to send error message if user stops communicating with bot?

Tags: c#, frameworks, botframework, bots

How can I get my bot to send an error message if the user has stopped communicating with it for a certain fixed time (30)?

Comment: Microsoft Bot Framework to enable your bot to prompt the user if the bot detects inactivity and ultimately end the conversation if no user activity after a defined period of time in C#

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post the same as an answer if you've found what you were looking for. Thanks!